# ehci_hcd kernel panic debug

Tags: kernel

I am getting kernel panic with EIP: ehci_irq+0x125/0x3d0 [ehci_hcd]. Can't figure out how to debug this problem. It's happening randomly. My old Eee 1015CX serves as small home server for openvpn, etc. The only device which is connected is USB wifi adapter with rtl8822bu driver. I am using that to create hotspot. Any help is highly appreciated. Kernel version: 5.10.0-20-686, Debian 11 32bit.

Note: I have 3 USB 2.0 ports.

Computer is freezed right after the error occures, so this dump photo is "the only crumb" I have.

[image]

`lsusb`

```
Bus 005 Device 003: ID 04f2:b26f Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd USB2.0 0.3M UVC WebCam
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 2357:0115 TP-Link Archer T4U ver.3
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

Comment: Does the problem still happen when the USB device is removed?

Comment: I can test it. Error appeares in frequency of several days.. I use it as always-on comp.

Comment: A lot of the panic is cut off so I can't see all the details, but sometimes computers have internal devices that use a USB driver. What is the output of `lsusb`?

Comment: @forest lsusb added, WebCam is built-in